# get_json_obj _fails for SelectExpr() but works for Select in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark3

i am facing a strange issue , i am trying to display values of my JSON object, it works fine with `select()` but it dont work with `selectExp()`, i get a weird error, following in my implementation,

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("JsonPractice").getOrCreate()
my_json_df = spark.range(1).selectExpr(
    """'{"sample_json":{"sample_json1":["1st_vale","2nd_val"]}}' as my_json_column""")
my_json_df.selectExpr(get_json_object(col("my_json_column"), "$.sample_json.sample_json1[1]")).show(2)
my_select_expr = get_json_object(col('my_json_column'), '$.sample_json.sample_json1')
my_json_df.selectExpr(my_select_expr).show()
```

I am getting following error

> raise TypeError("Column is not iterable")
> TypeError: Column is not iterable

Comment: what is your expected output ??

Comment: My expected out is `["1st_vale","2nd_val"]` which i can get using select , but when i try to do same with selectExpr it fails

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to specify `col` while using **`selectExpr`**

```
my_select_expr = "get_json_object(my_json_column, '$.sample_json.sample_json1')"
my_json_df.selectExpr(my_select_expr).show(10,False)

#or    
my_json_df.selectExpr("get_json_object(my_json_column,'$.sample_json.sample_json1')").show(10,False)
#+-----------------------------------------------------------+
#|get_json_object(my_json_column, $.sample_json.sample_json1)|
#+-----------------------------------------------------------+
#|["1st_vale","2nd_val"]                                     |
#+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
my_select_expr=get_json_object(col('my_json_column'),'$.sample_json.sample_json1')
my_json_df.select(my_select_expr).show(10,False)
#+-----------------------------------------------------------+
#|get_json_object(my_json_column, $.sample_json.sample_json1)|
#+-----------------------------------------------------------+
#|["1st_vale","2nd_val"]                                     |
#+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: cant we evaluate  `my_select_expr = "get_json_object(my_json_column, '$.sample_json.sample_json1')"` , without quotes? like this `my_select_expr = get_json_object(my_json_column, '$.sample_json.sample_json1')` ?

Comment: @noobie-php, That's possible with `.select` as select accepts `col,strings`, Please check the Updated answer!